# Reassigning an array frees the memory used by it?

Tags: php, arrays, memory-management, garbage-collection

My class has a member variable array, items. Periodically I reassign the array to be the value of another, temporary array, like this:

```
$temp = array();
$temp[] = new Object();
$temp[] = new Object();
$temp[] = new Object();
... etc.

$this->items = $temp;
```

So, could I have a memory leak? By reassigning the value of $this->temp to a new value, $temp, would all the items (the items are objects) originally in $this->temp still linger around, or would they be freed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not cause a memory leak. $temp and $this->items are just references to the same array. Since PHP is a garbage collected language, the array will be deleted (garbage collected) when there are no more references to the array.

Answer (score 1):

They will linger around for a little while, but in PHP they will be freed eventually by the [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)).

Comment: This is also the case in Java, C#, and other memory-managed languages. Note that this is **not** the case in C/C++, which have no garbage collector; any memory allocated by `new` (`malloc()`) must later be freed by `delete` (`free()`)