# For cleared or unset php arrays, are elements garbage collected?

Tags: php, arrays

if I unset an array, would its elements be garbage collected or freed up assuming they are not referenced in anywhere else?
what if I simply do $array =new array();

```
$array = array('a'=>1);
//method 1 to clear array
unset($array);
```

method 2 to clear an array

```
$array = array('a'=>1);
//method 2 to clear array
$array y = array();
```

Comment: 1. destroyed 2. destroyed and created (overwritten)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does reassigning an array to another array free memory originally used by the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119376/does-reassigning-an-array-to-another-array-free-memory-originally-used-by-the-ar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check-out [php < 5.3 garbage collection, do array values need to be set null or does setting the array = null orphan all its elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826066/php-5-3-garbage-collection-do-array-values-need-to-be-set-null-or-does-setting), maybe that will help answer your question.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer, at least in my opinion.  Scrolling down to the answers section and seeing a redirect is what life was like back in the days of forums.  Good find, though!

Answer (score 5):

Following simple code answers the question:

```
        $a = array();
        $a[0] = 'a1';
        $a[1] = 'b2';

        foreach($a as $v)
            echo $v . '<br />';
        //writes content of array

        echo count($a) . '<br />';
        //writes 2

        $a = array(); //CLEAR ARRAY

        foreach($a as $v)
            echo $v . '<br />';
        //writes nothing

        echo count($a) . '<br />';
        //writes 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will modify the array itself and leave it empty:

```
array_splice($myArray, 0);
```

And the [Splice Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)